# Packer Error: "amazon-ebs: Error querying AMI: AuthFailure"

Tags: windows, powershell, amazon-web-services, packer

I'm trying to create the packer build seen here: https://www.packer.io/intro/getting-started/build-image.html

```
PS C:\dev\tutorials\packer> packer build -var 'aws_access_key=AKI---------' -var 'aws_secret_key==+---------------------------------------' example.json
amazon-ebs output will be in this color.

==> amazon-ebs: Prevalidating AMI Name...
==> amazon-ebs: Error querying AMI: AuthFailure: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
==> amazon-ebs:         status code: 401, request id: []
Build 'amazon-ebs' errored: Error querying AMI: AuthFailure: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
        status code: 401, request id: []

==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> amazon-ebs: Error querying AMI: AuthFailure: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
        status code: 401, request id: []

==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
```

I've tried giving my user the `AmazonEC2FullAccess` policy in AWS.
Is my command correct?

I am on windows 8, using powershell.

Comment: Full Access or not, it cannot even *authenticate* you. Are you sure your secret key starts with `=+`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The credentials come in a `credentials.csv` file. I opened this file with Excel, clicked column C2 and copied the value there. This is an issue because excel prepends an equals sign at the beginning of the value box :/ That was my problem.

Comment: Use `Import-Csv` to import it in PowerShell to avoid that kind of issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help @MathiasR.Jessen.

The credentials come in a `credentials.csv` file. I opened this file with Excel, clicked column C2 and copied the value there. This is an issue because excel prepends an equals sign at the beginning of the value box :/